# Clarification of Shift operator for $\tau_a\sin(2\pi x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For the standard shift operator $\tau_a$ which does the following to a function
$$\tau_a f(x) = f(x-a)$$
I'm having some confusion for functions such as the following:

For $\sin(2\pi x)$, which of the following would be correct?
$$\tau_a\sin(2\pi x) = \sin(2\pi(x-a)) = \sin(2\pi x-2\pi a)$$
or
$$\tau_a\sin(2\pi x) = \sin(2\pi x - a)$$

Comment: x is shifted, not $2\pi x$ so your first option is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should think as following,
$$f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$$
and
$$f(x-a) = \sin(2\pi (x-a))$$